# nightwatch - terminate all test suits when a single test fails

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, nightwatch.js

Is there a way (e.g. flag) to terminate whole nightwatch tests when a single failed test occur? Or to get at least a status code that the some test failed, within the program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "test_settings" section of your nightwatch.json,  add the following entry:

"end_session_on_fail": true

It looks promising.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick. It starts still with the next test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try creating a global in global.js and set it to true:

"abortOnAssertionFailure: true"

Answer (score 0):

You can run each test suit by different npm script, such as-

```
"test1": "nightwatch --retries=1 ./src/tests/test1.js",
"test2": "nightwatch --retries=1 ./src/tests/test2.js"
```

and then you can run this npm script-

```
"run_tests": "npm run test1 && npm run test2"
```

is one test case will fail in 'test1' the npm command will fail as well and no other tests case/suits will run.